# Having a logic error when compiling C++ program that is supposed to represent arbitrarily large numbers as a string

Tags: c++

This is actually a homework problem, I've had people be irritated with me before for asking about school stuff but I feel like this is the best place to ask, I appreciate your help in advance!

Instructions:
The Bigint class represents arbitrarily large integers (values larger than can be supported with unsigned long long int data types) as C++ string objects, and supports addition of these values.

At this point, my code is compiling okay, but the output is not at all what I am looking for.

I tried adding a cout statement before the return statement in the add function so I could see what the value of my_return ended up as, but that statement didn't even execute at all. This is my first time using dynamic arrays. Also, this is the second rewrite of the program that is having the same incorrect result.

```
#include <iostream>                // Standard streams
class     Bigint
{
public:
    // Six Pack
    Bigint();                                  
    Bigint(std::string);                         
    Bigint(const Bigint &);                      
    Bigint(Bigint &&);                          
    Bigint & operator = (const Bigint &);        
    Bigint & operator = (Bigint &&);             

    // Input and output
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &, const Bigint &);
    friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream &, Bigint &);

    Bigint operator + (Bigint) const;            // Addition


private:
    std::string              value;
    std::string              add(std::string, std::string) const;
};

// Private Member Function
std::string Bigint::add(std::string left, std::string right) const {
    int needed_length, left_length, right_length, carry = 0;
    int * left_array = NULL;
    int * right_array = NULL;
    int * sum_array = NULL;
    std::string my_return;
    left_length = static_cast<int>(left.length());
    right_length = static_cast<int>(right.length());

    if (left_length > right_length) {
        needed_length = left_length;
    } else if (left_length < right_length) {
        needed_length = right_length;
    } else {
        needed_length = left_length;
    }

    left_array = new int[needed_length];
    // store left string into left_array backwards
    for (int indx = 0; indx < left_length; indx++) {
        left_array[indx] = static_cast<int>(left[left_length - 1 -indx]);
    }

    right_array = new int[needed_length];

    // store right string into right_array backwards
    for (int indx = 0; indx < right_length; indx++) {
        right_array[indx] = static_cast<int>(right[right_length - 1 - indx]);
    }

    sum_array = new int[needed_length + 1];

    for (int indx = 0; indx < needed_length; indx++) {
        sum_array[indx] = (left_array[indx] + right_array[indx] + carry) % 10;
        if (left_array[indx] + right_array[indx] + carry >= 10) {
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
    sum_array[needed_length] = carry;

    // reverse contents of sum_array and store in a string
    for (int indx = 0; indx <= needed_length; indx++) {
        my_return[indx] = static_cast<char>(sum_array[needed_length - indx]);
    }

    delete [] left_array;
    delete [] right_array;
    delete [] sum_array;
    return my_return;
}

// Standard Six Pack
Bigint::Bigint() {      
    value = ' ';
}

Bigint::Bigint(std::string my_string) {        
    value = my_string;
}

Bigint::Bigint(const Bigint & other) {          
    value = other.value;
}

Bigint::Bigint(Bigint && other) {      
    value = other.value;
}

Bigint & Bigint::operator = (const Bigint & other) {   
    value = other.value;
    return *this;
}

Bigint & Bigint::operator = (Bigint && other) {      
    value = other.value;
    return *this;
}

// Input and Output
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & outstream, const Bigint & other) {
    for (int indx = 0; indx < static_cast<int>((other.value).length()); indx++) {
        outstream << other.value[indx];
}
    outstream << std::endl;
    return outstream;
}

std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & instream, Bigint & other) {        
    std::string temp;
    instream >> temp;
    for (int indx =  0; indx < static_cast<int>(temp.length()); indx++) {
        other.value[indx] = temp[indx];
    }
    return instream;
}

// Arithmetic
Bigint Bigint::operator + (Bigint other) const {       
    std::string str1, str2;
    str1 = value;
    str2 = other.value;
    Bigint my_return(add(str1, str2));
    return my_return;
}

int main()
{
    Bigint    var_a, var_b;

    // Input
    std::cout << "Enter two big integers on a line: ";
    std::cin >> var_a >> var_b;


    // Display result
    std::cout << "Sum of " << var_a << " + " << var_b << " = " << var_a + var_b << std::endl;

    // All done
    return 0;
}
```

The expected results are as follows:
Enter two big integers on a line: 88999988888 7777777777777777
Sum of 88999988888 + 7777777777777777 = 7777866777766665

Actual results:

Enter two big integers on a line: 88999988888 7777777777777777
Sum of 8
 + 7
 =

Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: Not the answer, but your copy/move constructors/assignment operators are unnecessary. Your compiler will generate them for you if you omit them. (Also your move constructor and assignment operator copy the string rather than moving it, which can make your program slightly slower.)

Comment: If your print statement doesn't execute, add more print statements before it until one executes. That way, you know where the execution stopped.

Comment: My teacher is requiring the copy/move constructors and assignments operators.

Comment: There are at least three errors in your code.  This is a good time to learn to use your debugger.  Start with small numbers (a one and a two digit number).

Answer (score 0):

**This is wrong**:

```
std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & instream, Bigint & other) {        
    std::string temp;
    instream >> temp;
    for (int indx =  0; indx < static_cast<int>(temp.length()); indx++) {
        other.value[indx] = temp[indx];
    }
    return instream;
}
```

There is no need for `temp` and it is also incorrect to use it. It is incorrect because its length will be larger than `Bigint::value` which is a problem for `other.value[indx]` (it is larger in `main`'s usage where `var_a` and `var_b` each have a length of one)

**Instead just do this**:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& instream, Bigint& other) {
    instream >> other.value;;
    return instream;
}
```

Likewise you don't need a loop in `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Bigint&);` either

---

**This is probably not doing what you are expecting**:

```
for (int indx = 0; indx < left_length; indx++) {
    left_array[indx] = static_cast<int>(left[left_length - 1 -indx]);
}
```

For the input `"12"` `"34"` the `"12"` part will be executed by this loop and `left_array` will have the values `50` and `49` instead of `1` and `2`. This is because those are the ASCII values of `'1'` and `'2'`

**Instead convert like this**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < left_length; i++)
    left_array[i] = left[left_length - 1 - i] - '0';
```

Subtracting by `'0'` has the effect of subtracting `48`. Converting to `int` is automatic, no need for the cast

---

**Likewise the conversion back needs to change**:

```
for (int indx = 0; indx <= needed_length; indx++) {
    my_return[indx] = static_cast<char>(sum_array[needed_length - indx]);
}
```

`my_return` has a length of zero when it is being written to so the first thing to do is resize it. Then you can write each character by doing the reverse of the previous conversion. Also the indexing was off by one

**Changed**:

```
my_return.resize(needed_length);
for (int i = 0; i < needed_length; i++)
    my_return[i] = static_cast<char>(sum_array[needed_length - i - 1] + '0');
```

Comment: Thank you!! I am better off now having heeded your advice: new output is:           Enter two big integers on a line: 88888 9999999
Sum of 88888 + 9999999 = 

Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: Your welcome, there is still something funny going on with `add`, reading it

Comment: Yeah I noticed that this is what my program is spitting out now: Enter two big integers on a line: 12345 12345
Sum of 12345 + 12345 = 0x100701a10
0x100701290.         I tried to add a few print statements in add so I could see the backwards arrays but none of those are executing

Comment: I made another update to add, I meant to include this line:     sum_array[needed_length] = carry;
but forgot, now it is there after the for loop that sums the arrays, although I still have the same output     Enter two big integers on a line: 5678 1234
Sum of 5678 + 1234 =

Comment: @AmandaPanda, I seem to be getting the correct output after having made the changes

Comment: Mine is still not working correctly. Here is my stream operator overloads:
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & outstream, const Bigint & other) {     // << operator
    outstream << other.value;
    return outstream;
}

std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & instream, Bigint & other) {            // >> operator
    instream >> other.value;
    return instream;
}

Comment: Okay it works now!!!!!!!!  thank you thank you. I hadn't seen what you mentioned about the conversions and now it is working.